# runtime problem with second example of HelloWorldApplet

Tags: java

I'm following the course "Teach Yourself Java in 21 Days"
(https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/user/gchen/www/download/java/LearnJava.pdf)

I have a problem with the second example:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;


class HelloWorldApplet extends java.applet.Applet {

    public void paint(Graphics g) { 
    g.drawString("Hello world!", 5, 25);
    }
}
```

The compiling of this Java code generates 2 warnings:

```
warning: [serial] serializable class HelloWorldApplet has no definition of serialVersionUID
class HelloWorldApplet extends java.applet.Applet {
^
2 warnings
```

When I execute this code with

```
java HelloWorldApplet
```

I get

```
Error: Main method not found in class HelloWorldApplet, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
```

or

```
a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Comment: Looks like you chose an outdated course to follow. Applets have not been used since, more or less, the beginning of the 21st century. You need an Applet-compatible browser to run an applet, though I think there is a tool provided with the JDK, or there used to be, which simulates the browser. It's best to avoid Applets altogether.

Comment: What's wrong with that PDF? It has a verbose description on how to run an applet just on that very page...

Comment: Note that the course you are following is from 1996, which means it is ancient and very much out-of-date. You will be much better off by following a newer tutorial, such as [Oracle's Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't completed the course, please read ahead and follow the example 1.3

Example 1.2 Only tells you to compile the code.

Example 1.3 tells you how to see the code in the html page.